# Buttons not working in IOS5

Tags: button, view, ios5, ibaction, xcode4.2

i built an app on ios 4.3 and it worked fine but when i run it on the new ios the back buttons dont work. Heres my code to go to the next xib:

`-(IBAction)Selection3Page:(id)sender;{
    //show next view
    Selection3Page * nvc = [[Selection3Page alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:nvc animated:NO];
    [nvc release];
}`

and this is the code to return back to the first xib:

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender{
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

}

please help!!

Answer (score 4):

The API for dismissing modal views was changed somewhat in iOS 5. Try this instead:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)])
{
    NSLog(@"didTouchDoneButton 5.x");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"didTouchDoneButton 4.x");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please vote up the answer and mark it as correct if it answered your question.

Comment: i cant becuase im not a high enough rank yet =/ sorry

Answer (score -1):

post some `NSLog`s in there somewhere and check if the methods are actually getting called... I would start around that..

Comment: how would i be able to do that here? sorry im new to coding

Comment: Place this inside the functions, at the top...

`NSLog("Function called");`

When clicking on the function, check the log if this comments appear... Correctly placing the NSLogs could help you find where the program stops working...